# Can we search for >1 predicate?

Tags: support, search

I tried the following searches:

```
[harry-potter] isaccepted:1 answers:1
      => 0 results

[harry-potter] isaccepted:0 answers:1
      => 0 results

[harry-potter] isaccepted:1
      => 900+ results

[harry-potter]  answers:1
      => 630 results
```

Seems that searching for >1 predicate in the same search doesn't work.

Is this an official limitation of search? A bug in search? An error in my query #1?

Comment: For us non-programmers, what exactly are you trying to figure out with your code? Just curious. What does "predicate" mean in this context?

Comment: @Slytherincess - all the HP questions with no accepted answers and <=2 answers (or at least >=2) answers

Comment: Thanks! Was just wondering :)

Comment: Dupe-closing this since I've now posted a definitive proposed-FAQ question about the search facility (and made sure to mention that `isaccepted:` works for **answers only** and `answers:` works for **questions only**!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can,

```
[harry-potter] views:250 hasaccepted:1
    => 212 results
```

The issue you are having is that you are using a predicate that searches for ***answers** that are accepted answers(or not)* : `isaccepted:1` and one that searches for ***questions** that have a minimum number of answers(or no answers)* : `answers:1`.

It returns no results because there are no answers that are questions, or questions that are answers, so it cant find something that is both *an answer that is an accepted answer (or not)* **AND** *a question that has a minimum number of answers(or no answers)*.

---

**To get the exact result you needed, you have to change `isaccepted` to `hasaccepted`:

```
[harry-potter] hasaccepted:0 answers:1 
    => 160+ results
```